# Java: Address already in use

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

I'm trying to create a simple class that can is able to send files over a network. Basically, this class is created once on each machine, a separate listening thread is started, and it can send and receive files. At this point I've hard-coded the other addresses (to a loopback) and the file-locs in order to simplify testing.

Here's my class:

```
public class ConnectionHandler  extends Thread{

    private ServerSocket sSocket;
    private Socket socket;

    public ConnectionHandler(){
        try {
            this.sSocket = new ServerSocket(6533);
            this.socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6533);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendFile(File f) {
        try {
            int count;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

            while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
              out.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }

            out.flush();
            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){

        try {
            int count;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            InputStream in = sSocket.accept().getInputStream();
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(location));

            while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
              out.write(buffer, 0, count);
              out.flush();
            }

            out.close();
            in.close();
            sSocket.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

However, I'm running into a 'Address already in use' error and cannot figure out the issue within my code. Additionally, I recognize that my 'run' thread terminates after one transmission, this is intentional for testing. I plan on implementing a more robust thread that can handle multiple connections, etc.

Comment: Check that you don't have any other processes (maybe even a previous java execution of this code) listening on port 6533.

Comment: I don't have any other processes on that port.

Comment: Pretty sure your server and client should be different modules. The purpose of creating a client/server system is so you could distribute the client without any server code in it.

Comment: Can you verify that you are getting the `Exception` on the `new ServerSocket(6533);` line?  Any chance an old version of your application is still running?

Comment: Each node needs to act as a server and a client. I am writing code for a server (which has other responsibilities) which will not be distributed with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I'm running into a 'Address already in use' error and cannot figure out the issue within my code

Any chance you are trying to fork *multiple* `ConnectionHandler` threads?  That would try to start *multiple* server sockets on more 6533 and the 2nd one would throw an exception.

Typically the main thread starts the server socket and a `ConnectionHandler` is forked after a connection is accepted.  Something like:

```
// main or server thread
ServerSocket  serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6533);
try {
   while (!shuttingDown) {
       Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
       // better would be to use an ExecutorService thread-pool here
       new Thread(new ConnectionHandlerRunnable(socket)).start();
   }
} finally {
   serverSocket.close();
}
```

Comment: I'm only ever creating this class once, that's what I thought this issue was initially as well. It looks like I didn't save the class that is responsible for this, I was in fact creating the same class twice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something else is listening to port 6533. `netstat` will tell you what.

Comment: Nothing else is listening on that port.

Comment: 'Something else' could include you. Maybe *you* are trying to listen on that port multiple times?